# Calling outer class' method getContentPane() from inner Action class

Tags: java, jframe, abstract-action

I want to call outer class' method getContentPane() from inner Action class. I don't understand why my code doesn't work.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    public MainFrame() {
        super("My app");
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu myMenu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(myMenu);
        Action myAction = new AbstractAction("Do everything") {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        };
        myMenu.add(myAction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `validate();` method after `getContentPane().add(...);`.

> The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its
>   subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's
>   subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or
>   layout-related information changed) after the container has been
>   displayed.